# Detecting %s mixed with named placeholders in python interpolation

Tags: python, string-interpolation

So apparently, Python will allow

```
'%s %(var)s' % {'var': 'x'}
```

which produces

```
"{'var': 'x'} x"
```

I'm writing something where I basically want python's named placeholder substitution features only. Is there any way to detect a mix of named and positional placeholders?

**EDIT**: The context of this is that I'm writing something that's sort of a templating tool. After writing a bunch of stuff with %(named)s all over the place, you then call template.substitute(dict) to go and replace everything. I'm trying to prevent the case where people leave `%[srfd,etc]` in the string(because they forgot to interpolate or something) by throwing an error if it's been left there.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but for new code the recommendation is to use the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of the `%s` syntax.

Comment: Are you able to replace the `%s` with `%%s`?

Comment: @aganders3 may end up doing that, a fair bit of code to change though

Comment: @gnibbler just str.replace() it? I suppose, but I'd rather be able to throw some meaningful error if there are any unnamed placeholders

Comment: @aganders3 Unfortunately, even if he switched to that he'd still have the same problem. `str.format`, like the old `%` method, supports both positional and keyword substitutions.

Comment: @nik3daz, perhaps just `if '%s' in foo:....`. You would have to check for all the other placeholders too

Comment: @gnibbler Hah, this simple solution will actually work decently. It turns out you DON'T need to check all the others. `%s` and `%r` are the **only** ones that could possibly go wrong and even then, **only** as the first placeholder value in the string (as far as I can see)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *str.__mod__* builtin function isn't reprogrammable.  There isn't a way to selectively turn-off some of its features.

You could however use a regex to locate the positional placeholders and escape them prior to string interpolation:

```
>>> d = {'var': 'x'}
>>> template = '%s %(var)s'
>>> esc_template = re.sub(r'(%[^()]*[sdf])', r'%\1', template)
>>> esc_template % d
'%s x'
```

Answer (score 2):

If Raymond Hettinger tells you how it's done, you listen, because he's right :)

Another option is to subclass [`string.Template`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) to define your own substitution logic and syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Not an instant-fix option, but to expand on agander's comment, using `str.format` does at least guarantee you don't accidentally fill in any non-named placeholders without seeing an error. This is because it separates out the positional substitutions from the named ones by using proper method call syntax:

```
>>> '%s %(var)s' % {'var': 'x'}
"{'var': 'x'} x"
>>> '{} {var}'.format(var='x')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    '{} {var}'.format(var='x')
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> '{} {var}'.format(8, var='x')
'8 x'
```

There's a side benefit I use quite often to Python supporting *two* different substitution syntaxes, though it's a bit of abuse of featuritis. Since I write a lot of code that assembles SQL queries to pass to a DB interface, which uses `%s` for placeholders for parameterised queries, I do all my outer-level query pasting with `str.format`, which leaves the `%s` placeholders completely unmolested without having to continually escape them.

```
>>> '%s {var}'.format(var='x')
'%s x'
```

If that's the reason you have `%s`s that you expect to be passed through in your output, `str.format` could simplify your life a lot.